# Finding $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In the following problem I need to consider the function defined by $f(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ if $x\ne 0$ and $0$ if $x=0$

I am trying to calculate $f'(x)$ for $x\ne0$. Then after calculating that use that to show that $f''(0)=0$

To calculate the first part I need to use the rule that,

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ but how do I plug in the values I need then find my second part of my question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

---

Then, for $x\ne0$,

$$f'(x)=\frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}$$

while for $x=0$ we see that

$$\begin{align}
f'(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}-0}{x-0}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, we have

$$\begin{align}
f''(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}-0}{x-0}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that the limits here are best dealt by letting $x=\frac1u$ and taking the limits as $u\to\pm\infty$ by L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Or even simpler $$\frac{1}{e^{1/x^2}}\le 2x^4\implies \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}<2x\to 0$$

Comment: Well, it's not entirely intuitive for me, but I suppose it would work.  :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt For $x>0$, $e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+O(x^3)\ge \frac12x^2$.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.