# finding $f'''(0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

---

I am trying to calculate $f''(x)$ for $x\ne0$ then try and use that to calculate $f'''(0)=0$

Then, for $x\ne0$,

$$f''(x)=\frac{e^{-1/x^2}(4-6x^2)}{x^6}$$

while for $x=0$ we see that

$$\begin{align}
f''(0)=?
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, we have

$$\begin{align}
f'''(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f''(x)-f''(0)}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{e^{-1/x^2}(4-6x^2)}{x^6}-0}{x-0}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

But in the second step how do I find $f''(0)$

Comment: @Michael $f''(0)=0$.  What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188734/finding-fx/2188740#2188740), I showed that $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$.

Here, we have for $x\ne 0$, $f''(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\frac{4-6x^2}{x^6}$

Hence, we can write

$$\begin{align}
f'''(0)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)-f''(0)}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}\frac{4-6x^2}{x^6}}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(4-6x^2)}{x^7e^{1/x^2}}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

To see this last step, we can use $e^t=1+t+\cdots +\frac{t^4}{4!}+O(t^5)>t^4/4!$ for $t>0$.  Hence

$$\frac{(4-6x^2)}{x^7e^{1/x^2}}<\frac{(4-6x^2)4!x^8}{x^7}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Every derivative of the given function as the origin equals zero (so the given function is "horribly smooth" at the origin, but not analytic). For any $n\geq 1$, $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ applied to $e^{-1/x^2}$ gives a polynomial in $\frac{1}{x}$ times $e^{-1/x^2}$, say $p_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-1/x^2}$, and

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^{\pm}} p_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-1/x^2} = \lim_{z\to \pm\infty} p_n(z) e^{-z^2} = \color{red}{0}.$$